# C Variable Not Updating on Thread Iteration

Tags: c, struct, iterator, pthreads, memory-barriers

I'm writing a parallel program which uses multiple pthreads to manipulate values in a square matrix until it reaches a specified point. I'm using pthread barriers to signal the threads to start and let main() know when to update the matrix.

Basically, I have two matrices:

- readMatrix: contains the current iteration values for writeMatrix to use.
- writeMatrix: updated by a calculation run by the thread using readMatrix values.

Once an iteration is done, the read and write matrices are swapped. The loop then moves on using the updated read matrix.

However, there is a problem; on iteration, the read matrix values that have been swapped are not stored.

I am using a struct to pass all pointer variables to the initiated thread:

```
struct matrixStruct {
    double** readMatrix;
    double** writeMatrix;
    int dimension;
    int totalThreads;
    int threadNumber;
    int lowerBound;
    int upperBound;
};
```

Here is where the threads are initiated in main() and then the working loop which controls the threads, swaps the matrices and checks if it has met the goal yet:

```
pthread_t threads[totalThreads];
int rc;
long t;
for( t = 0; t < totalThreads; t++)
{
    structInstance[t].readMatrix = readMatrix;
    structInstance[t].writeMatrix = writeMatrix;
    structInstance[t].dimension = dimension;
    structInstance[t].totalThreads = totalThreads;
    structInstance[t].threadNumber = t;
    structInstance[t].lowerBound = t*innerCellAmountByThread;
    structInstance[t].upperBound = findUpperBound(t, innerCellAmountByThread, totalThreads, remainderOfCells);
    rc = pthread_create(&threads[t], NULL, initiateThread, &structInstance[t]);
    if (rc)
    {
        printf("ERROR; return code from pthread_create() is %d\n", rc);
        exit(-1);
    }
}

int precisionCheck = 0;
// Working while loop
while(precisionCheck != 1) {
    // Start all threads
    pthread_barrier_wait(&barrier1);

    // Wait for them to finish
    pthread_barrier_wait(&barrier2);

    // Swap matrix and then check for precision
    double** tempMatrix;
    tempMatrix = writeMatrix;
    writeMatrix = readMatrix;
    readMatrix = tempMatrix;

    precisionCheck = verifyPrecision(readMatrix, writeMatrix, precision, dimension);
}
```

And here is what each thread does:

```
void *initiateThread(void *structArg) {
    struct matrixStruct *structInstance = structArg;
    double** readMatrix = structInstance->readMatrix;
    double** writeMatrix = structInstance->writeMatrix;
    int dimension = structInstance->dimension;
    int totalThreads = structInstance->totalThreads;
    int threadNumber = structInstance->threadNumber;
    int lowerBound = structInstance->lowerBound;
    int upperBound = structInstance->upperBound;

    printf("threadNumber: %d lower: %d upper: %d\n\n", threadNumber, lowerBound, upperBound);

    while(endFlag == 0) {
        pthread_barrier_wait(&barrier1);

        relaxMatrixWithBounds(readMatrix, writeMatrix, dimension, lowerBound, upperBound);

        pthread_barrier_wait(&barrier2);
    }

    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

So to summarise, I need readMatrix to actually store the updated value on an iteration.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: So the swapping occurs in the main thread and you want
the swap to be visible in all the other threads?

Comment: yeah, and in main after the iteration.

Comment: Why not store the matrix pointers as a 2-element array (`double **matrix[2]`), initialize them to `readMatrix` and `writeMatrix`, respectively. Then have a global flag to say which is the `readMatrix` and which the `writeMatrix`. Just toggle the flag to swap them. You don't even need to store them for each thread since they're all using the same one.

Comment: Good idea. So the current way I am doing it is the reason why it won't keep the data after an iteration?

Comment: You're only swapping the main thread's pointers. The worker threads still all have their old pointers (unless I'm missing something). Actually, you could probably just make the main thread's variables global and have the other threads just use them (take readMatrix and writeMatrix out of the struct).

Comment: Great, I think I've got it now. Cheers ooga.